# Android mobile not connect in eclipse while run particular application

Tags: android

I am trying to connect my android phone to eclispe but i am unable to do so. Its not identifying the device. I didn't get any error. I have checked my usb ports.They are all in working condition.

Comment: Are you sure that you have configure the particular device drivers.

Comment: please check devices in command line with adb.
fire command : "adb devices" so it will give list of devices.

Comment: so it will give list of devices. so its determine that adb work fine or not

Answer (score 0):

Please go to settings-> developer options-> make usb debugging option checked. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Another application with ADB may be running。 Try to close all applications that may use adb then try to connect to the device in eclipse again.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't have your developers option activated you have to go to (like you can see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp07dPusJNA)):
   **settings ->About phone -> build number (click 7 times)**
2. Now you do what @pratik said:
   **settings -> Developer Options-> USB Debugging (check the check box)**
3. Change your device to another usb port.

Comment: and the drivers for your device? Try to reboot your pc and your mobile.

Comment: @user1722880 do you have any other devices connected to the adb?